# Are there any comment templates to put under bad questions?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed some kind of like a trend. If a question is bad, I almost always see a comment like

> Provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

or

> Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Those comments are usually really similar, so I started searching for a list of those. I am not able to find anything, and here is my question: can anyone provide a unified list of those so people like me can use them?

Comment: There are various [magic links documented here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I need. I want to get a list of comments, not links, since it's not always easy to see those rephrased.

Comment: Adding pro-forma comments is generally discouraged. Write something pertinent to the situation each time.

Comment: Since everything on Stack Exchange is under the CC-BY-SA license, I created by own longer comments and I'm reusing those when appropriate. While most of mine can be reused as is in a lot of cases, I generally edit them to fit the situation.

Comment: That list of longer comments seems to be exactly what I'm asking for.

Comment: here is a list: https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments/tree/master/sites/stackoverflow.com and its instructions on how to use them: https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments but it is best, as with any pre-cooked list, to follow the advice from @Scratte and edit them to fit the case.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Repository of useful pro-forma comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136609/165773)

Comment: I edit mine to fit the situation. But mostly it's exactly the same few situations. And I don't downvote & comment at the same time if the poster can (revenge) vote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my list, in JSON for convenience:

```
[]
```

I am only half joking. If the question is bad, it is not uncommon to stumble upon unreasonable users who will not be happy to be told that their question has problems and will not be answered. As such, leaving a comment will make you a target for abuse. That they were built from a community curated list does not fully prevent this lash out either.

It's not hard to find concrete examples of this happening out there. This is mentioned in various other Meta questions, including the FAQ on mandatory feedback along with downvotes:

[Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin) : *"Many experienced users will tell you that they used to leave helpful comments along with their downvotes, but have stopped doing so because of the unpleasant blowback they received from unreasonable users. Even for those users who remain rational, commenting about votes almost inevitably leads to extended, off-topic discussions, which we strive to avoid."*

But the problem applies even if you did not cast a vote, because there's no way of telling whether an existing downvote was from you or someone else, and unreasonable folks can get upset anyway.

While I understand that this deviates from the original intent of the question, it's worth leaving a warning that whichever canned comment repository you use, you must be prepared for what may follow after leaving the comment, for better or worse. As also suggested, tailoring the canned comment to the question may increase the chance of a positive outcome.

Comment: +1 for the great list, I independently developed an identical one

Comment: Over the years, I've slowly improved my list to be exactly the same as yours. Use votes/flags to indicate what you would otherwise post as a comment. If you're going to leave a comment, it should not be pro-forma. Rather, write something specific and unique to the situation, e.g., giving the person specific concrete advice on how to improve their question.